# How to save a Chinese character  in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf, utf8mb4

I am unable to save the character  on mySQL 5.5. I have tried collation utf8mb4 and utf32. I have to store both Chinese and English characters in the same table.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/globalization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to save this charecter by using utf8mb4 charecterset on mysql server. So the output of show variables like 'char%'; should be all utf8mb4 except for perhaps system charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try `utf8 general`, and also, don't change to execute

```
 SET NAMES utf8;
```

beore the actual query, which is quite an important part

Comment: That doesn’t help here — in fact, it is likely the problem OP is facing. The U+25683 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-25683 character is a supplementary Unicode symbol, and therefore cannot be stored using MySQL’s `utf8` encoding. [It needs `utf8mb4` instead.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)